# monitor Google pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using grafana to monitoring my service, I have new service that deal with google pubsub using spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub, I wanna monitoring the pubsub subscription to show how many message acknowledged and how many one in lag, is there any way to implement that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use google [StackDriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) to monitor the volume of messages in percentage rather then see exactly how many messages there ware and how many acknowledged.
You can save in you db all messages and acknowledgment if you really like.